# Match function in Regular expressions being null?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, null, match

I seem to be getting an error message in visual studio saying

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input
```

when I try doing
`Match BirthYear2 = Regex.Match(kvpInd2.Value.birth.date, BirthPattern2);`

I was wondering it was possible to allow the Match function to produce a null? Basically, I dont mind if the `kvpInd2.Value.birth.date` doesnt contain the expression

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `kvpInd2.Value.birth.date` is not null?

Answer (score 11):

In your case, [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz) is not *producing* a `null`, you are *passing* it a `null` as its first parameter.

> Exceptions:
>   ArgumentNullException - `input` or `pattern` is null.

If you would like to make `null` inputs valid, you could change your call as follows:

```
Match BirthYear2 = Regex.Match(kvpInd2.Value.birth.date ?? "", BirthPattern2);
```

This will return with no match (assuming that `BirthPattern2` does not match empty strings) when `kvpInd2.Value.birth.date` is `null`, rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely issue here is that `kvpInd2.Value.birth.date` is `null`.  `Regex.Match` won't throw an exception if the pattern isn't found, but will throw the exception you're seeing if the input is null.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value is null before you do your match. Done. Or, am I missing something? Another option, I guess is you could do: `kvpInd2.Value.birth.date ?? ""`. That will treat a null as an empty string which (hopefully) your pattern would not match.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing all that property chain, you'll need to check if no object in the chain is null.

```
if(kvpInd2 != null && kvpInd2.Value != null && kvpInd2.Value.birth != null && kvpInd2.Value.birth.date!= null) {
    Match BirthYear2 = Regex.Match(kvpInd2.Value.birth.date, BirthPattern2);
    ...
}
```